# What is the shortest command to print out a variable's name and value?

Tags: python

When debugging I often put in print statements to see a variable's value. I also like to print out the variable's name to prevent confusion. Is there a shorter command to to type to print what I want than:

```
print("very_long_variable_name=", very_long_variable_name)
```

Typing the variable name twice seems like extra work that a computer should be able to automate.

I would write a function that does this that is shorter to type:

`printv(very_long_variable_name)` or `printv('very_long_variable_name')`

But it seems that writing either of these functions is not easy. Is there some Python package that has this function?

Answer (score 1):

Defining a function that prints a variable's name and value is pretty difficult. You have to access the stack frame of the calling code, and look up the variable there:

```
import inspect

def printv(varname):
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back

    value = sentinel = object()
    for scope in [frame.f_locals, frame.f_globals, frame.f_builtins]:
        if varname in scope:
            value = scope[varname]
            break

    if value is sentinel:
        value = '???'
    else:
        value = repr(value)

    del frame
    print('{} = {}'.format(varname, value))
```

But it's not always possible to look up a variable's value based on its name. It works for global and local variables:

```
x = 'global x'

def func():
    x = 'local x'
    printv('x')

printv('x')  # output: x = 'global x'
func()       # output: x = 'local x'
```

But something surprising happens if you try to print the value of a variable that's never used in a nested function:

```
x = 'global x'

def func():
    x = 'local x'

    def nested():
        printv('x')

    nested()

func()  # output: x = 'global x'
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do that with the `eval` keyword.

```
def printv(variableName):
     print(variableName + ' : ' + eval(variableName))
```

Comment: That only works if the variable is a global variable. And in the same module as the `printv` function.